# Install Windows 8 for second time failed

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-8, uefi, grub2

I've installed Windows 8 successfully and activated it. Then for some reasons it crashed with blue screen (I guess because of wrong VGA driver installed)

Now I can't install the same OS from the same DVD! It states some installation files are corrupted. (When `Expanding Windows Files`)

I thought that there was a problem with that DVD, so I burned an iso to another disk. Same thing happened. Windows 8 installed the first time, but no chance with second time. (I really tried so many times)

Is Windows installable only once from a DVD?! I know it's a stupid question :)

**PS** I can't install my old Windows 7 any more and get the same error at installation. I have an Ubuntu 12.04 installed alongside Windows.

Can this be related to UEFI? How can I get rid of?

Edit:

I tried both Hiren's hard disk check and `badblock` tool from Ubuntu. Everything is reported healthy in hard disk. But installation still has no success :|

Added some screenshots of Windows 8 and Windows 7 installation
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you were getting this with Windows 7 it sounds like a pure drive problem.  As to the reason you cannot install Windows 8 more information is required.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I think so. But can't fix the issue. Even can't find it!

Comment: Test your RAM for errors using memtest86+. Also, have you tried formatting your Windows partition from Linux before attempting the install (after backing up your data of course)?

Comment: @sorush-r This error in 90% of cases there is any problems with memory or with the memory controller. Try playing a game of tag memory module like putting two in the second and third slots. You can also install the system with one module of memory. But before that, test the memory. Karan rights.

Comment: @STTR I already tried formatting from Linux, but it's still same. Now I have installed a 64 bit Windows XP (temporary). I'll try memtest. Thanks

Comment: I would definitely wipe the hard drive from linux level using something like /dev/zero which will fill the drive with zeros making it as never used. Then i would check if there is a UEFI mode or Legacy/BIOS and tried to install the system using both of them if the first try fails. Is your Windows 8 installation disk a full system installation or is it an upgrade version only?

Comment: @mnmnc It's a full installation. I deleted System Reserved and C: partitions when installing

Comment: @sorush-r System Reserved partition is necessary for correct system installation. If you deleted the one from the previous installation - that is ok as long as you make sure new installation will create another one for itself. Have you tried switching to Legacy/BIOS and install Windows 7 after that?

Comment: @mnmnc New installed creates it automatically. Sorry I didn't understand... What should I try? What's Legacy/BIOS ?

Comment: @Karan Memtestx86+ is running now. It found 7000+ errors! What can I do to fix

Comment: @sorush-r Every Windows Installation creates a system reserved partition. When you choose a drive during the installation, the installation wizard should inform you that this partition will be created.

Comment: 7000+ errors with memtest86+?! Try reseating your RAM modules, swapping them, perhaps cleaning the contacts. If you still get errors after this, buy new RAM.

Comment: @Karan I just removed one of my RAMs and everything is ok now. It has a lifetime warranty. I'll return it back to seller tomorrow. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, I ran into this same error message when doing a test installation of Windows 7 to a computer that had two [EFI System Partitions (ESPs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and/or that had a FAT16 ESP. To diagnose the problem, I recommend booting to Ubuntu and doing a `sudo parted /dev/sda print` operation in a terminal. This should produce output like the following:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA Hitachi HDP72505 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                     Flags
 1      1049kB  200MB  199MB  fat32        EFI System               boot
 2      200MB   411MB  211MB  ext2         Gentoo /boot
 3      411MB   621MB  210MB  hfs+         Unused
 4      621MB   500GB  499GB               Linux LVM data (nessus)  lvm
```

That's from one of my computers, and it obviously lacks any Windows installation. It shows a FAT32 ESP, which is denoted by the `boot` flag. Look for either *two* partitions with `boot` flags or an ESP with a `fat16` filesystem type.

If you have two ESPs, you can either consolidate them and delete one *or* temporarily remove the `boot` flag from the ESP you *don't* want Windows to use.

If you have a FAT16 ESP, I recommend converting it to FAT32. This will necessitate backing up the partition's contents, creating a fresh FAT32 filesystem on the partition, and restoring the data. You'll also need to change Ubuntu's `/etc/fstab` file to refer to the filesystem by its new "UUID" (really just a serial number).

If you need more help with any of these options, post back with more details, such as your `parted` output.

Comment: Check the comments section above. The problem (bad RAM) has already been diagnosed and taken care of.